# SELECT-FROM inside an IF STATEMENT

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, select, plsql

It is not very clear to me if I can use a select-from statement as a condition for an IF STATEMENT
For example

```
IF(SELECT quantity
  FROM warehouse)>(SELECT quantity
                  FROM warehouse2) then ecc
```

Can I do something like that?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: No, you can't. There is no `if (implicit cursor) then...` syntax in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should using the variable for them.

```
DECLARE 
    V_quantity_WH1 NUMBER;
    V_quantity_WH2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
    --Sum qty 1 --------------
    SELECT SUM(quantity) INTO V_quantity_WH1 FROM warehouse;

    --Sum qty 2 --------------
    SELECT SUM(quantity) INTO V_quantity_WH2 FROM warehouse2;

    --Compare qty1 and qty2 ----------------
    IF (V_quantity_WH1 > V_quantity_WH2) THEN
        ......;
    END IF; 
END;
```

Comment: Agree. This is clearer for people to parse. Inlining a select statement makes little or no sense to me. I can't see how it would benefit anyone.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. The `select ...` expression is a pointer, IF expects a boolean expression: `IF *boolean_expression* THEN *statement* END IF;`